# Unity touch event on overlayed objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having a problem on controlling what touch event should trigger upon touching an object. The problem is, my background has a touch function and it is overlayed by a button, when I tap the button the background also detect a touch function even though I don't want it to happen. How can I make the button only respond when I tap it, or the background only respond when I actually tap on itself.

it's like in Corona SDK you put a "return true" at the bottom of your function to make the touch event only respond on the object rather than going all the way.

Comment: Have you tried out [IsPointerOverGameObject](http://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject.html)?

Comment: How am I suppose to use IsPointerOverGameObject? I really don't like the docs of unity unlike corona

Answer (score 0):

found the answer here, Unity docs is really hard to understand especially for beginners, unlike CoronaSDK docs it's very user friendly

here is the link on how to do this:
[Credit to guy in here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVZiv7DLU6E)